# Toggle alert from bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the following alert and I want it to be toggle after 2 sec,how should I do that ?

```
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        data was saved
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight-how can you provide example?

Comment: Using jQuery: `setTimeout(function() {$('.alert.alert-info').toggle(); },2000);`

Comment: Did you use the default way for bootstrap to enable the alert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#alert').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/cetoh/1/edit)

Comment: They don't have an `alert` id, they use a class. Your answer wouldn't work.

Comment: My answer is just an example, I prefer ID's than classes. Because $('#id') the fastest selector in jQuery.

Comment: The OP may not have a choice as to what the HTML looks like, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with setTimeout like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        // Do something after 2 seconds
        $('.alert').show();
    }, 2000);
```

The `.alert` should be `display:none;` by default.

Answer (score 2):

use a `setTimeout` :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alert-info').hide();
}, 2000);
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/JAFmx/**

Answer (score 2):

For the default way, as is described on their website:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

```
setTimeout(function() {
$(".alert").alert('close')
}, 2000);
```

Comment: +1 for using the right bootstrap approach `alert('close')` I dont think it makes so much difference, but good suggestion!